# How to deploy from CircleCI to Google Compute Engine?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, circleci

I want to deploy CircleCi's artifacts to Google Compute Engine after CI test, 
but I got stuck in SSH key issues.
When `gcloud compute copy-files` ran, gcloud will ask for ssh key generating during CircleCI's deployment process, which I don't know how to handle.

> WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
>   WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
>   WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
>   WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
>   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
>   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):

I've looked into document [here](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/google-auth/) and [here](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/google-cloud-platform/#google-compute-engine-and-google-container-engine), but none of them mentioned SSH related topics. So what SSH key should I use and how can I pass it to gcloud securely?

[UPDATED]
Here's my commands in the deployment step.

```
  - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
  - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --quiet components update
  - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
  - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID
  - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute copy-files ./dist instance-1:/tmp/ --zone $GCLOUD_INSTANCE_ZONE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First error:*

> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):

- You have to add the `--quiet` flag.

> gcloud compute copy-files
>
> This command ensures that the user's public SSH key is present in the project's metadata. If the user does not have a public SSH key, one is generated using ssh-keygen(1) (if the --quiet flag is given, the generated key will have an empty passphrase).

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files

*Second error:*

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

- add a user before the instance name `338234243-compute@instance-1:/tmp`
- remove the last `/` of the instance path `instance-1:/tmp`
- Check the owner of the tmp directory (user you choose should have a R&W right)

It seems that the user by default of my generated ssh key was `root`, and GCC sshd is not allowing root connection...

Comment: @choasia don't hesitate to comment if its not solving your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry for my late since I just finished my vacation. I will try your solution soon.

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and upon tinkering more and reading the [google cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-with-travis-ci), I realized I needed to generate an ssh key.

I use CircleCI (this also works with TravisCI) and this was the command I added to my `circle.yml` file to generate the ssh key:
`- ssh-keygen -q -N "" -f ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried it but got `Updating project ssh metadata...-Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
` when circleci was running the copy-files command `gcloud compute copy-files ./dist instance-1:/tmp/ --zone $GCLOUD_INSTANCE_ZONE`. Any idea on it, or have you ever met it?